# How to drag and drop UIbutton inside MGLMapView? mapbox ios

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I have a problem with the UIButton on the MGLMapView viewcontroller.

When I try to drag and drop a UIButton and I execute after my iOS application I see my map (mapbox) but not my button.

How can I add buttons in my mapbox mapview (MGLMapView) ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This should be as simple as dragging and dropping the button onto the map. It could be that you have inadvertently dropped the button below the map depending on how you brought the button onto your Interface Builder file. Check in the document outline and drag the button so that it is a subview of your map if necessary. It could also be a constraint problem but that's hard to tell without seeing your setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should drag and drop the UIButton in the same level as the map view and to the bottom of the map view.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i know this, but when i add UIButton in my main.storyboard and i add this source code in the ViewController:

```
import Mapbox

class ViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

let url = URL(string: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10")
let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds, styleURL: url)
mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
mapView.setCenter(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 59.31, longitude: 18.06), zoomLevel: 9, animated: false)
view.addSubview(mapView)
}
}
```

my UIbuttons are no longer visible after i running the ios app. 
yet they exist in my main.storyboard.